# What is the purpose of placing a HashSet inside of a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashset, symbol-table

For example:
private HashMap<Integer, HashSet> variableName;

I understand that HashMap implements Map and doesn't allow duplicate keys and HashSet implements Set and doesn't allow for duplicate values, but what is the purpose of placing a HashSet inside of a HashMap? Do they not achieve similar tasks by themselves (though in different ways and with different performance)? What functionality does doing this provide that a HashMap by itself couldn't?

Comment: Same reason you would put **anything** in a `HashMap`, you want to associate a key (here an `Integer` value) with something (in this case a `Set` of other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this when you want to map a key to *more than one* thing.  A Map can only map a key to a single thing, but that single thing can be a Set which holds multiple things.